# Implementing a third party widget script in a React app?

Tags: reactjs, import, widget

my company wants to implement a third party widget into a React app. The third party company gives us a pre ES6 script to embed in 'the footer of your html file.' So

`<script>// iife function here // </script>`

The widget should show up on every page no matter the route or React re-render of the DOM. In other words, at the highest point of the React app structure. Of course if I try to put the script in `App.tsx`, there are a million errors because it's pre-ES6 and not typed. Where should something like this go in the app? Is it in `index.jsx`? Create a module to be imported?

Answer (score 0):

Third party script // iife function here //  should be placed on the public folder index.html file. That will load the script globally to all the pages.

Answer (score 0):

Define a typescript module and type it manually if you want, type it as `any` otherwise
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

If the external module exposed by the iife is not relevant to your react project. Feel free to code inside `<script>` tag in index.html